# OS X Application for Scraping HTML of a Set of Tweets

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, twitter

I recently went to a Tweetup event and want to scrape from my Twitter account all the tweets made during that either by selecting a date/time range or by matching to a hash tag.

Is there an app to pull all these tweets out (hopefully with links intact) and all so I can "archive" them on my own web site?

Comment: You should probably ask the "web app" part of the question in [webapps.se]. It is off-topic here.

Comment: @LoïcWolff But the OS X part is most definitely on topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Storify.com](http://storify.com) is a pretty cool way to curate something like the Tweetup you mention.  It lets you search for tweets (or other social media) and stream it into a list of points to make up your story.

I first noticed Jason Kottke using it a couple of days ago to make a [story out of the tweets from Gavin Purcell about production of that night's Jimmy Fallon show.](http://storify.com/jkottke/how-a-late-night-talk-show-works)   I have been fascinated by it ever since.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add them to google calender or iCal. You could try http://twistory.net/

From there the data will be accessable for you to do whatever you want :-)

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up using this site

http://twitprint.com/

and then just didn't print, but rather viewed the source and copied out the body contents..

Did some search and replace stuff to style it better (and to remove their inline styles).

Comment: Still would love to have a desktop app to do this though...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Twitter application installed on your Mac, and you feel like doing some things with AppleScript, you should be able to make your own application to do this.

Comment: Care to share some sample code for this?

Comment: I haven't actually finished writing it because I haven't had time, but you need the Twitter suite, XML suite and the Internet suite. All are included except for the twitter suite, which comes with the twitter app. It is also possible without the Twitter suite, but I haven't looked into it yet.